# Correct way to pause a Python program

Tags: python, sleep

I've been using the `input` function as a way to pause my scripts:

```
print("something")
wait = input("Press Enter to continue.")
print("something")
```

Is there a formal way to do this?

Comment: Work in a debugger and use breakpoints?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

It *seems* fine to me (or `raw_input()` in Python 2.X). Alternatively, you could use `time.sleep()` if you want to pause for a certain number of seconds.

```
import time
print("something")
time.sleep(5.5)    # Pause 5.5 seconds
print("something")
```

Comment: I know about the sleep function in the time module but what if I have a long block of text I want the user to read?

Comment: Simply use `print` to display the long block of text and then `input()` or `raw_input('Press <ENTER> to continue')` as appropriate for your version of Python.

Comment: For a long block of text, it is best to use `input()` (or `raw_input()` on Python 2.x) to prompt the user, rather than a time delay.  Fast readers won't want to wait for a delay, slow readers might want more time on the delay, someone might be interrupted while reading it and want a lot more time, etc.  Also, if someone uses the program a lot, he/she may become used to how it works and not need to even read the long text.  It's just friendlier to let the user control how long the block of text is displayed for reading.

Answer (score 44):

*For Windows only*, use:

```
import os
os.system("pause")
```

Comment: This is Windows specific, whereas all of the existing answers are platform independent.

Comment: why would python implement a function that is OS specific? It makes no sense.

Comment: os.system() calls a system function called "pause" – a ubuntu for example doesn't know what "pause" is, so it will return with: _sh: 1: pause: not found_

Comment: I know this is probably not what the question wanted, but it helped me a lot.

Comment: If you are calling the python script from a Windows Batch File, you can add `pause` to the end of the batch file instead of putting a command at the end of the python file, and you will get the same effect.  This way the python file is OS independent, while the batch file could only ever be used in Windows anyway.

Comment: Is this equivalent to `signal.pause()`? (Which I believe works on Linux)

Answer (score 22):

So, I found this to work very well in my coding endeavors. I simply *created a function* at the very beginning of my program,

```
def pause():
    programPause = raw_input("Press the <ENTER> key to continue...")
```

and now I can use the `pause()` function whenever I need to just as if I was writing a batch file. *For example*, in a program such as this:

```
import os
import system

def pause():
    programPause = raw_input("Press the <ENTER> key to continue...")

print("Think about what you ate for dinner last night...")
pause()
```

Now obviously this program has no objective and is just for example purposes, but you can understand precisely what I mean.

NOTE: For Python 3, you will need to use `input` as opposed to `raw_input`

Comment: How is this different from what is stated in the question?

Answer (score 18):

I assume you want to pause without input.

Use:

[time.sleep(seconds)](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Comment: Yes, the search engines leads to this question.

Comment: This requires `import time`.

Answer (score 10):

I have had a similar question and I was using signal:

```
import signal

def signal_handler(signal_number, frame):
    print "Proceed ..."

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.pause()
```

So you register a handler for the signal SIGINT and pause waiting for any signal. Now from outside your program (e.g. in bash), you can run `kill -2 <python_pid>`, which will send signal 2 (i.e. SIGINT) to your python program. Your program will call your registered handler and proceed running.

Comment: Note that this is not portable across platforms, eg. on Windows there is no `signal.pause`.

Comment: What platform did you try it on? Linux?

Comment: You don't even need the handler, you could just do `signal.pause()` inside a `try` block with `except KeyboardInterrupt: pass`.

Answer (score 8):

```
print ("This is how you pause")

input()
```

---

Comment: This seems to result in an error: `NameError: name 'Print' is not defined`

Comment: @PeterMortensen That is due to the blank space between "Print" and "("This is how you pause")".

Comment: Python is case sensitive, so lowercase `print` is required to call the function.  You can even keep the space between the function name and the opening parenthesis without getting an error.

Answer (score 8):

I use the following for Python 2 and Python 3 to pause code execution until user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
import six

if six.PY2:
    raw_input("Press the <Enter> key to continue...")
else:
    input("Press the <Enter> key to continue...")
```

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by [mhawke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21945/mhawke) and [steveha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166949/steveha)'s comments, the best answer to this exact question would be:

Python 3.x:

```
input('Press <ENTER> to continue')
```

Python 2.x:

```
raw_input('Press <ENTER> to continue')
```

> For a long block of text, it is best to use `input('Press <ENTER> to continue')` (or `raw_input('Press <ENTER> to continue')` on
> Python 2.x) to prompt the user, rather than a time delay. Fast readers
> won't want to wait for a delay, slow readers might want more time on
> the delay, someone might be interrupted while reading it and want a
> lot more time, etc. Also, if someone uses the program a lot, he/she
> may become used to how it works and not need to even read the long
> text. It's just friendlier to let the user control how long the block
> of text is displayed for reading.

Anecdote: There was a time where programs used "press [ANY] key to continue". This failed because people were complaining they could not find the key ANY on their keyboard :)

Answer (score 5):

Very simple:

```
raw_input("Press Enter to continue ...")
print("Doing something...")
```

Comment: I've used this method a bit, however I also like using it as a pause() function and I don't think there's a need for exit(). def pause(): return raw_input("Press Enter to continue ...")

Comment: `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`

Answer (score 4):

***cross-platform way; works everywhere***

```
import os, sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    os.system('pause')
else:
    input('Press any key to continue...')
```

Comment: If the platform is windows, use the pause command of windows batch scripting. If it's not windows, use the python input() function to pause for input. After the input, the program will close.

Answer (score 3):

By this method, you can resume your program just by pressing any specified key you've specified that:

```
import keyboard
while True:
    key = keyboard.read_key()
    if key == 'space':  # You can put any key you like instead of 'space'
        break
```

The same method, but in another way:

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):  # The same. you can put any key you like instead of 'space'
        break
```

Note: you can install the [`keyboard`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) module simply by writing this in you shell or cmd:

```
pip install keyboard
```

Answer (score 2):

I work with non-programmers who like a simple solution:

```
import code
code.interact(banner='Paused. Press ^D (Ctrl+D) to continue.', local=globals())
```

This produces an interpreter that acts almost exactly like the real interpreter, including the current context, with only the output:

```
Paused. Press ^D (Ctrl+D) to continue.
>>>
```

The [Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) is also a good way to pause.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace() # Python 2
```

or

```
breakpoint() # Python 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I like this solution:

```
import getpass
getpass.getpass("Press Enter to Continue")
```

It hides whatever the user types in, which helps clarify that input is not used here.

But be mindful on the OS X platform. It displays a key which may be confusing.

[image: It shows a key, like I said]

---

Probably the best solution would be to do something similar to the *getpass* module yourself, without making a `read -s` call. Maybe making the foreground color match the background?

Answer (score 1):

user12532854 [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61148042/11422004) using `keyboard.readkey()` but the it requires specific key (I tried to run it with no input args but it ended up immediately returning `'enter'` instead of waiting for the keystroke).

By phrasing the question in a different way (looking for `getchar()` [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48820375/is-there-a-built-in-function-in-python-3-like-getchar-in-c) in python), I discovered readchar.readkey() does the trick after exploring `readchar` package prompted by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48820501/11422004).

```
import readchar
readchar.readkey()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to stop the execution is the *time.sleep()* function.

If you need to suspend the execution only in certain cases you can simply implement an *if* statement like this:

```
if somethinghappen:
    time.sleep(seconds)
```

You can leave the *else* branch empty.

Answer (score 0):

For cross Python 2/3 compatibility, you can use `input` via the `six` library:

```
import six
six.moves.input( 'Press the <ENTER> key to continue...' )
```

Answer (score 0):

On POSIX:

```py
import signal

try:
    signal.pause()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print("Waiting time is over!")
```