# Is there a built-in function in Python 3 like getchar() in C++?

Tags: python, c++, input, getchar

I want to do user input in python which is similar to **getchar()** function used in c++.

c++ code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
char ch;
while(1){
    ch=getchar();
    if(ch==' ') break;
    cout<<ch;
}
return 0;
}
```

Input: stack overflow

Output: stack

In the above code, when a space input from the user than the loop breaks.
I want to do this in python using **getchar()** type function as I used in c++ code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user
I have seen this but I need built-in function way in python  3.
To more clarify my question, I have given c++ code.

Comment: then your question title should have been something like _"Is there a built-in function in Python 3 like getchar() in C++?"_.  Regardless, it seems like the possible answers are in that original question.

Comment: @milton. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48820501/3091398). The second method (using STDIN) is using built in function.

Comment: @codelt Thanks a lot! it clears me

Comment: @justin I am sorry for that.

Comment: @milton Not a problem just trying to make the questions and answers helpful to the community.

Answer (score 15):

**Easiest method:**

Just use split function

```
a = input('').split(" ")[0]
print(a)
```

**Using STDIN:**

```
import sys
str = ""
while True:
    c = sys.stdin.read(1) # reads one byte at a time, similar to getchar()
    if c == ' ':
        break
    str += c
print(str)
```

**Using readchar:**

Install using `pip install readchar`

Then use the below code

```
import readchar
str = ""
while(1):
    c = readchar.readchar()
    if c == " ":
        break
    str += c
print(str)
```

Comment: One more question! @Codelt
Is it store in the buffer register when I am using sys.stdin.read(1) for each character input?

Comment: @milton. Yes, the whole input is in the buffer and we are reading it byte by byte.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me @Codelt

Comment: First example does not appear to work with Python 3. With input `hello world` it will split this into `hello` and `world` and the 0th element is `hello`. Not a single character.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant verify using input: `stack overflow` and output: `stack`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick

```
ans = input().split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: Input requires the user to hit 'enter', that's not what's asked. Accidentally, the split() is useless here. Why did you add this ? To 'clean' the output ? Rather use strip() then.

Answer (score 2):

[`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) provides access to some useful capabilities on **Windows** platforms.

```
import msvcrt
str = ""
while True:
    c = msvcrt.getch() # reads one byte at a time, similar to getchar()
    if c == ' ':
        break
    str += c
print(str)
```

`msvcrt` is a built-in module, you can read more about in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch).

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick. (Probably does not work on Windows)

```py
import sys
import termios

def getchar():
    old = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
    cbreak = old.copy()
    cbreak[3] &= ~(termios.ECHO|termios.ICANON)
    cbreak[6][termios.VMIN] = 1
    cbreak[6][termios.VTIME] = 0
    termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin,termios.TCSADRAIN,cbreak)
    char = sys.stdin.read(1)
    termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin,termios.TCSADRAIN,old)
    return char

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = getchar()
    print("Key is %s" % c)
```

Here, the function `getchar()` prepares standard input to read only one character at a time using cbreak, meaning that you don't have to press enter for `getchar()` to read a key. This function works with all keys except for the arrow keys, in this case it will capture only the escape character (27)

Answer (score -1):

## Python 3 Solution:

```
a = input('')        # get input from stdin with no prompt
b = a.split(" ")     # split input into words (by space " " character)
                     # returns a list object containing individual words
c = b[0]             # first element of list, a single word
d = c[0]             # first element of word, a single character
print(d)

#one liner
c = input('').split(" ")[0][0]
print(c)
```