# How to delay a command in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say we have two commands:

```
print("Hello")
print("How are you?")
```

If we execute this, we will get these two sentences printed.

I want the command 2 to be executed after 5 seconds the command 1 is executed. Is it possible to achieve this in Python?

Comment: please specify if you want to just wait for 5 seconds or run the second command in an async manner, meaning that if you put a 3d command after the 2d one, the will get executed in the order: `1, 3, [delay] 2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to pause Python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552320/correct-way-to-pause-python-program)

Comment: Haven't checked it! Thanks for informing my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

```
import time     

print("Hello")
time.sleep(5)
print("How are you?")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

see [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import the time function
the only code you need is:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

this function will make the code sleep (delay)

so you can just us

```
import time

print('Hello') 
time.sleep(5) 
print('How are you')
```

this will first execute the first line then sleep for 5 seconds then print how are you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).