# How can I pause a Python script every x minutes?

Tags: python, scripting

Looking for a way to pause (and then later resume) a Python script every x minutes (with a small random +/-). The original script would run over and over and then every x minutes it would pause for a set amount (again with a random +/-) then continue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552320/correct-way-to-pause-a-python-program

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import random

# this will pause between 1 & 10 minutes, randomly.
time.sleep(60*(random.randint(1, 10)))
```

Comment: Will this pause FOR 1-10 minutes, or will it pause EVERY 1-10 mins?

Comment: This will pause for 1 - 10 min. (Random). If you have need an specific time you can change to this:

time.sleep(60*5)  #this will pause for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example code using `random.uniform()` to generate a random float and `time.sleep()` to wait for a given time.

```
import random
import time

BASE_DELAY = 60   # base amount in seconds
RAND_MAX = 30     # high end of random in seconds
RAND_MIN = -30    # low end of random in seconds

running = True

def do_stuff():
    #do stuff here, maybe setting running to False
    pass

def loop():
    while running:
        time.sleep(BASE_DELAY + random.uniform(RAND_MIN, RAND_MAX))
        do_stuff()

loop()
```

Comment: Where would I include my original code? Sorry, I'm new to coding.

Comment: You can either replace the call to `do_stuff()` with the things you want to do, or you can add them instead of `pass` inside the `do_stuff` function. (By the way, I like to help, but please try to find solutions to your problems yourself first. Maybe watch a Python Tutorial that covers the basics - there are lots of really good resources out there. The concepts I used here are loops and functions, so it's relatively simple stuff)